# rest api action

Tags: php, zend-framework, rest

m developing rest api by zf.
this is my user controller.

```
<?php
class UserController extends Zend_Rest_Controller
{

    public function init()
    {
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    }

   public function indexAction()
    {
         $this->getResponse()
            ->appendBody("From indexAction() returning all articles");
    }

    public function getAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()
            ->appendBody("From getAction() returning the requested article");

    }

    public function postAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()
            ->appendBody("From postAction() creating the requested article");

    }

    public function putAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()
            ->appendBody("From putAction() updating the requested article");

    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()
            ->appendBody("From deleteAction() deleting the requested article");

    }


}
?>
```

By running this url `http://quickstart.local/user/`  m getting

```
From indexAction() returning all articles
```

and by running this url `http://quickstart.local/user/1`  m getting

```
From getAction() returning the requested article
```

how can i test post, put , delete action.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to send POST, PUT and DELETE request via CURL to your controller's URL.. Zend_Rest_Controller will automatically route that request to appropriate action.

Thanks!

Comment: m using window so is there any other method

Answer (score -1):

hii

follow this pattern

```
http://quickstart.local/controller/action_name
```

Sanil

Comment: try renaming ur get action to some other action and try again

Comment: You can't really call HTTP POST, HTTP PUT and HTTP DELETE methods that way. It's not the matter of the url form, it's the matter of how HTTP request is produced.